# Excel - How to find the middle point between two identical values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a string of 1's and 2's in a column.  It's mostly 1's with a few 2's scattered about.

I want to find the middle point between the 2's.

I've attached an image that shows what I want to achieve.  If there are any other methods or ideas that can accomplish what I'm looking for that would be awesome.

If it's not clear from the picture, I'm trying to move the 0's to the middle of the area that is bordered off without having to merge and center cells by hand.

[image: Excel]

Comment: Sorry, it's kind of hard to see the link to the image.  It's the 'Excel' hyperlink below 'Thanks!' but above the 3 excel tags

Comment: if you have the data in a table, then make a helper column called sort_me or some other name. make a helper formula that outputs an A if above the mid and not a zero, B if it is one of the Zeros, and C if it is below the mid. Then go to the sortme header and select the down arrow and sort. It will re-arrange your data as requested

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a helper column, which checks location of next `2` and calculates location of `0`:

Helper formula in the new column:
`=IF(C2=2,INT((ROW()+MIN(IF($C3:$C$22=2,ROW($C3:$C$22),"")))/2),"")`

Formula for placing `0`s:
`=IF(COUNTIF($D$2:D2,ROW())>0,0,"")`

[image]